# Capturing image from movie on memory stick inside camera without using a computer

Tags: camera-settings, image-processing, video, memory-card, camera

I'm in a dilemma.

Currently the computer in my house is a pentium 3 with Slackware 13 Linux OS. (Yes I know, stone-age compared to today's technology).

I also own an Canon EOS Rebel T4i EOS 650D camera that I take pictures and movies with.

I did manage to download the pictures and movies from the camera to my computer and tried opening the movies on my computer but the graphics is a bit mediocre, the sound quality is OK and the speed is a bit slow with stuttering. There was no issue with opening still pictures. The max colour resolution on the computer is also on the low side (16bpp).

I was looking in the camera manual for instructions to make a picture from the movie.

I don't mind if the picture is saved on the same stick, and I don't mind if the image format is PNG or JPG, and I don't care about the size.

What I did find in the manual were ways of creating "video snapshots" which allows one to create 2-8 second videos, and I was able to trim a video to a split second, but I want to be able to create an image file on the camera itself from a saved video without the need of a computer.

I would like to be able to also specify the frame I would like to save as well.

How can I do this with the camera model I have? And let's assume the stick with the video file on it is already inserted into the camera and ready to go and that the battery level is good.

Comment: Sounds like you want to extract a frame from a video? This is usually easiest to do with video editing software on a computer. If you know the timestamp of the frames you want to extract, you can use ffmpeg from the command line (won't have to wait for the video to load in an editor). See [Fastest way to extract frames using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957412/)

Answer (score 3):

Using a computer is still the easiest way, even if it is "a bit" old.

If you are concerned that the limited graphics capabilities would decrease the quality of your resulting photos, don't worry, the programs can easily save exactly what is decoded rather than what is displayed on the screen.

Example for linux (using mplayer)

```
mplayer -vf screenshot ENTER_YOUR_VIDEO_FILE_NAME_HERE
```

then you can rewind to the intended position using the cursor keys and press "s" to save a screenshot. Other keys: "o" - display the time, "[" and "]" slow down/speed up, "space" - play/pause, "." (dot) - skip to the next frame (for precise frame selection)